# yolo5 example android-app object detection export model from .pt to .ptl (torchscript)

Tags: python, android, export, object-detection, yolov5

[image]

I have one question, https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/tree/master/ObjectDetection I'm trying to use this manual (an android application for object detection) with the model from the manual - everything works perfectly, but when I try my model (exporting the model from pt format to ptl is ready), then the application it didn't work)))) I compare both in https://netron.app/ / - the same as a drop of water. In the bytecode, I note the same difference. Is this wrong? I only use the official export guide, where do I make a mistake?

`python export.py --weights ".\dataset\runs\detect\yolov5n_v1_50x2\weights\best.pt" --include torchscript` or `model.export(format='torchscript')` both of it not work

Comment: What is going wrong exactly? Export fails?